# Why Cells(Variable,"B") doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I create a small program and i really don't understand why my code can't work :O

```
For Each numberItem In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A01:A240").Cells
  Dim c As String
  Dim cpt As Long
  cpt = numberItem
  c = Cells(cpt, "B")    !!!!!ERROR !!!!!
```

If i put 1 instead of cpt, it is worked.
I didn't found something good on web. 
Is it something simple exist or not?

Thanks guys

Comment: 1004 error Application-defined or Object-defined error

Answer (score 4):

believe you just need to specify that you want the row:

```
For Each numberItem In Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A01:A240").Cells
  Dim c As String
  Dim cpt As Long
  cpt = numberItem.Row
  c = Cells(cpt, "B")
Next
```

Updated based on @omegastripes comment:

Let's say the loop is at cell A10 and that A10 has the value 37

Option 1: You want to use the row number from numberItem:

```
For Each numberItem In Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A01:A240").Cells
  Dim c As String
  Dim cpt As Long
  cpt = numberItem.Row
  c = Cells(cpt, "B")
Next
```

Result: `c = Cells(10, "B")`

Option 2: You want to use the value from cell A10, then slight adjustment

```
For Each numberItem In Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A01:A240").Cells
  Dim c As String
  Dim cpt As Long
  cpt = numberItem.Value
  c = Cells(cpt, "B")
Next
```

Result: `c = Cells(37, "B")`

Comment: Ok it is worked but i don't understand why, Cells take a int or long as parameter. Just why add .Row worked hahaha :O But thanks

Comment: glad it worked. Because numberItem is a range (starting at "A01"), numberItem.Row is number identifying the row

Comment: When i add a spy to numberItem is like 0 1 2 3 4 5, that's why i didn't understand my mistake :(

Comment: @MatDev8, that numbers 0 1 2 3 4 5 are the values of the cells, but not the row numbers of the cells.

Comment: Yeah ok ok i don't understand this part, thank you guys :)

Answer (score 2):

The name of your `NnmberItem` variable is misleading. In:

```
For Each numberItem In Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A01:A240").Cells
```

`numberItem` will be a cell, not a number. Therefore, as in Sam Gilbert's answer, you must still take the `Row` or `Value` property of the cell. Athough the `Value` property is the default property, apparently VB wants you to be more specific here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do that with a little bit change.
try:

```
Cells("B" & cpt)
```

Comment: That'd be `Range("B" & variable)`, but still not applicable in this case since the variable value is a range instead of a number.